# can not see pythons logs in azure app insight

Tags: python, azure

i have a python application using flask.i am using below code to send logs to azure insight using OpenCensus.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
format_str = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s'
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
formatter = logging.Formatter(format_str, date_format)
handler = AzureLogHandler(
     connection_string='InstrumentationKey=key')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

inside a function using

```
logger.warning(line)
```

when i try to log something i can see in console.when i try to move the log to azure insight i am not getting any exception but i am not getting those logs in trace result of azure app insight.can someone please help me in fixing this.